# How to insert a new column and fill it with another worksheet column values with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a new column and can only create a new column without being able to insert values. My goal is to insert column C from Sheet1 into column B from Sheet2 to get the result of Sheet3.

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

Sheet3:

[image]

Here is what I tried so far:

```
Sub AddColumn(length As Integer)
    Dim cell As String
    Dim form As String
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    Dim i, lastColumnNbr As Long
    Dim lastColumnStr As String
    lastColumnNbr = Worksheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1
    lastColumnStr = ColLetter(lastColumnNbr)
    ColumnName = Split(base, " ")
    Range(lastColumnStr & 1) = ColumnName(1)
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    For i = 2 To length
        cell = lastColumnStr & i
        form = "=TEXT("B"&i,"m/d/yyyy")"
        Range(cell).Formula = form
    Next
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Columns(LastColumnNbr).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: How do you know User ID 1 is Kayley?  If you have a list of IDs to match with Names, you won't need VBA for this - a simple `VLOOKUP()` can do it.

Comment: When you run that code, does it even come close to what you want it to do? Does it even work? What is the value of "base"?  The line `form = "=TEXT("B"&i,"m/d/yyyy")"` is going to produce a syntax error. This needs a lot of work.

Comment: @BruceWayne How do we use VLOOKUP with a reference to another worksheet ?

Comment: @StoneGiant base contains the name of the database, in this case I have development and production.

Comment: @octano the same way with any formula, just select the cell.